# Re-evaluation of Consumer Price Index (C.P.I.) weights

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, supply-and-demand, consumption, statistics

How are the **weights of the various household items in** the Consumer Price Index (**C.P.I.**) **basket decided**, i.e., how are they ***re-evaluated*** every year? Is it done manually or automatically?

**If** its done **manually**, *then how can they be sure* (i.e., what methods, statistical or mathematical) that the weights represent the general average consumption of that item in the household? **Else, if**  its done **automatically**, then what is the strategy (i.e., *what sort of algorithms or data structures*) used to ensure the accuracy of the weights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they are "sure", but the weights are based on the [American Consumer Expenditure Survey](http://www.bls.gov/cex/) which has a big sample size, a carefully chosen sampling frame, professionally executed sample gathering, and a large team of experts crafting questions and collating the data.

> ## How is the CPI market basket determined?
>
> The CPI market basket is developed from detailed expenditure
>   information provided by families and individuals on what they actually
>   bought. For the current CPI, this information was collected from the
>   Consumer Expenditure Surveys for 2011 and 2012. In each of those
>   years, about 7,000 families from around the country provided
>   information each quarter on their spending habits in the interview
>   survey. To collect information on frequently purchased items, such as
>   food and personal care products, another 7,000 families in each of
>   these years kept diaries listing everything they bought during a
>   2-week period.
>
> Over the 2 year period, then, expenditure information came from
>   approximately 28,000 weekly diaries and 60,000 quarterly interviews
>   used to determine the importance, or weight, of the more than 200 item
>   categories in the CPI index structure.

[Consumer Price Index Frequently Asked Questions (FAQs)](http://www.bls.gov/cpi/cpifaq.htm#Question_6)

> Consumer expenditure data supplied by the CE Survey are a critical
>   component of the CPI, as they are used to estimate weights for the
>   CPI’s consumer goods and services classification structure used in the
>   calculation of the CPI. In the construction of the CPI, four distinct
>   functional uses of CE Survey data are made: (1) to estimate biennial
>   expenditure weights, (2) to estimate monthly expenditure weights, (3)
>   to calculate the probability that an item’s price will be included in
>   the CPI calculations, and (4) to allocate expenditure estimates
>   between more-broadly defined expenditure categories from other survey
>   sources.

[Research highlights of the Consumer Expenditure Survey redesign](http://www.bls.gov/opub/mlr/2013/article/ce-survey-redesign.htm)

Page 6 of BLS Handbook of Methods, April 1997, [Chapter 16: Consumer Expenditures and Income](http://www.bls.gov/opub/hom/pdf/homch16.pdf) has a nice, detailed description of how "The estimation of population quantities of interest, such as the average expenditure per consumer unit on a particular
item category, is achieved through the use of weights." Be sure to check that out too.

Answer (score 1):

This goes on a tangent for this question here, but [Chevalier and Kashyap](http://www.nber.org/papers/w20768) criticize the basket that the CPI collects. To summarize, their point is that the basket is immune to sales: Holding goods in the basket constant while a seizable fraction of the population is hunting cheaper goods overestimates actual inflation, and vice versa in the "no sales" periods.